Android.bp rule dependencies
For an AOSP build, Instead of checking in binary artifacts to a git repo for embedding at build time, I want to download them from a maven repository. I have most of the logic down, but can't get the download rule (producer) to execute before the others (consumers).
Here's a shortened version of my Android.bp (the manifest.json file contains a list of artifact coordinates):
blueprint_go_binary {
    name: "downloader",
    srcs: ["src/download_artifacts.go"],
}

genrule {
    name: "download_artifacts",
    tools: [ "downloader" ],
    cmd: "$(location downloader) $(in) $(genDir)",
    srcs: ["manifest.json"],
    out: ["downloaded_artifacts"],
}

android_library_import {
    name: "SomeLib",
    aars: ["downloaded_artifacts:SomeLib.aar"],
    sdk_version: "current",
}

android_app_import {
    name: "SomeApk",
    apk : "download_artifacts:SomeApk.apk",
    certificate: "platform",
    privileged: true,
    system_ext_specific: true,
}

During make, I end up with the following error:
error: vendor/blah/packages/build/downloader/Android.bp:15:1: module "SomeLib" variant "android_common": module source path "vendor/blah/packages/build/downloader/downloaded_artifacts:SomeLib.aar" doe
s not exist
16:35:06 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

I never see my go program (which downloads these) run so of course the files are going to be missing.
What's interesting is that if I comment out all the imports and just leave the blueprint_go_binary and genrule, I see my program run (and fail as intended for now). However, it seems that my program runs in a later phase. It seems that the rules are first enumerated/evaluated and then executed and my failure happens at the evaluation stage.
What's the fix here? Is there a way to tell the system that these files will be there come execution time and to fail at that point?

This goes completely against the AOSP build system philosophy of having 100% deterministic builds by including all tools and all input materials in git. Going against their system will be difficult and is not recommended.

The artifacts are stored in maven and it's the same artifact that is downloaded every time. Checking in binaries into git is a pretty bad idea.

AOSP build system works in two phases, first phase is evaluate all build files (make and soong) to determine what needs to be built and how, the output of the first phase is used to create the ninja build script, second phase is execute ninja to actually do the build. If build files are not modified then first phase can be skipped.
